# Bash variable space in directory path

Tags: bash, variables, whitespace, alias

How can I remove a white space when I use a variable in a directory path.
For example, I'm trying to do

```
alias test='echo /david/$1'
```

and when I try

```
test hhh
```

this produces

```
/david/ hhh
```

with a white space before the variable. It seems very simple but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alias` doesn't do parameter expansion. At all. Use a function instead.

```
test (){
  echo "/david/$1"
}
```

Comment: To be more explicit, when you type `test hhh`, you are REALLY sending `echo /david/$1 hhh`, and because $1 is blank, you are sending `echo /david/ hhh`

Comment: Thanks! :) But, if I want to use an alias (in my .bashrc), must I specify that function there? What I was looking for is something like `alias ='command /path-with-variable ...` . Is there a way to put that function inside the alias specification?

Comment: mmm I just used the function instead the `alias` and the command works.

Answer (score 1):

man [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

> There  is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text.  If arguments are        needed, a shell function should be used (see FUNCTIONS below). [...] For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

As a part of alias expansion a space is added at the end of the expanded string (otherwise no argument could be added, like `alias ll='ls -l'`. So `ll -a` would be expanded to `ls -l-a` which would be wrong). So I see no solution to this problem anything else then to use function as [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) proposed.

Anyway using `test` as function or alias is not the best thing to do as it is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) built-in command (if no aliased or named a function). You can check how a mnemonic will be interpreted using the `type` bash built-in.

I defined an alias and a function called `test`:

```
$ type test
type test
test is aliased to `echo /xxx/'

$ type -a test
type -a test
test is aliased to `echo /xxx/'
test is a function
test () 
{ 
    echo "/yyy/$1"
}
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test
```

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies my question even more :)